# Can't upload or link to any images - Image tool seems broken

Tags: bug, uploader

I'm attempting to upload a profile picture using the uploader tool on Stack Overflow, but the tool appears to be broken. The file is not too large, it's only about 336 kB, which is well under the 2 MB limit, so I know that's not the issue, and even if it was, I'm not getting any error message.

What happens is when I drag the image file I want to upload into the "upload area" instead of uploading the image to the servers, it just opens the local file in my browser, which strikes me as the wrong action. I also don't get any option to browse my hard drive using a normal OS dialogue box to try and upload my profile pic that way either. The drag option is the only way I'm seeing.

Here are some screenshots:

*can't insert, image tool completely broken*

*Update: This issue seems to be with more than just the profile picture updates, but a general issue with the image upload/insert tool. I can't upload images or link to external images at all. It also loads way too big to fit on the screen, and I have to adjust the zoom feature to see the full popup.

This appears to be a bug with the image uploader tool. I'm using Chrome 58.0.3029.110 on Windows 8.1.

EDIT: I don't see any other questions that are as specifically about this **exact** issue. There are some similar ones but they're about some other specific issue that's different from what I'm reporting here. I'm reporting a general bug with the image upload tool, and doing a search, I see no other posts reporting this bug. Also, doing a quick check, this issue seems not to have been resolved yet, the tool is still broken in the exact same way as I reported almost a month ago.